# INPUT_MOUSE: mouse does not move with given dx/dy values

Tags: c++, mousemove

I am moving the mouse using INPUT to set the cursor position. This is fine, except that I cant use screen values to move the cursor. If I want to set the cursor from 0 to 1680, I have to use **1680*0.66 as dx** value to get the right position (inside game or on desktop).

(I use mousemove, as I am setting the cursor position inside a game, and absolute positioning doesnt work there. I have two screens, one is 1680 wide, the other one has 1280)

**Any Idea why I have to use this factor or where it comes from?** Thanks.

```
#define MOUSE_MOVE_FACTOR 0.6619

        //Set mouse pos:
        void setMousePos(int iX, int iY){


            iX = (int)((double)iX*MOUSE_MOVE_FACTOR);
            iY = (int)((double)iY*MOUSE_MOVE_FACTOR);


            INPUT *buffer = new INPUT[1];

            buffer->type = INPUT_MOUSE;
            buffer->mi.dx = iX;
            buffer->mi.dy = iY;
            buffer->mi.mouseData = 0;
            buffer->mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
            buffer->mi.time = 0;
            buffer->mi.dwExtraInfo = 0;

            SendInput(1,buffer,sizeof(INPUT));

            Sleep(100 + (rand() % 50));

        }
```

Comment: Can I say "Memory Leak"?

Comment: How do you know you have to use this factor? Did you just come up with a random number?

Comment: Games often change the video mode.

Comment: I just tried to set the mouse to 1680 at my desktop and came out with this factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably has something to to with mouse acceleration. Disabling it, leads to diffrerent mouse positions.

Answer (score 0):

Memory leaks can cause strange things to your application, and this may have an influence.

You are causing a memory leak every time this function is called by your second allocation of `buffer` at

`buffer = new INPUT[1];`

Answer (score 0):

As per the documention on [MOUSEINPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), dx/dy are relative coordinates if MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE is not set in dwFlags. Try:

```
 buffer->mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;
```

and see if that works. Note that you'll have to convert the X/Y to normalized absolute coordinates from 0-65535 as the documentation mentions.

I would also question why you are setting the position to (-3000,-3000) first. I would also guess you don't need the magic factor of MOUSE_MOVE_FACTOR which is probably due to mixing up relative/absolute mouse coordinates.

Edit: Re-reading your question and I missed that you may be using relative mouse position on  purpose. I would guess your absolute positioning might have failed due to not using normalized absolute coordinate (I wouldn't have guessed that myself without reading the entire documentation). Also note that 1680x0.66=1109 which is suspiciously close to 1024 and I might guess the game is running at a 1024x? resolution.

Comment: Yes, absoute positioning does not work here, as the game just looks for movements. The game is running in 1680x1050 too. Howerver it does no difference if I am in the game or on desktop.

Comment: Hmm, strange then. According to the docs the position should be in pixels and I can't think of anything offhand that would introduce a constant factor like that.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but just for anyone else. The documentation for [MOUSEINPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-mouseinput) and [mouse_event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event) explain that absolute positioning is normalized to the range 0-65535.

> If MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE value is specified, dx and dy contain
> normalized absolute coordinates between 0 and 65,535. The event
> procedure maps these coordinates onto the display surface. Coordinate
> (0,0) maps onto the upper-left corner of the display surface;
> coordinate (65535,65535) maps onto the lower-right corner. In a
> multimonitor system, the coordinates map to the primary monitor.

So the conversion would be x / (w-1) * 65535 and y / (h-1) * 65535.